# Using Django CreateView to handle formset - It doesnt validate

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

### The problem

I'm trying to modify the class-based view 'CreateView' to handle a formset instead of a form.

When client does a GET request, the formset is displayed to the client correctly.
The problem is when the client submit the form with a POST.

When Django recieve POST, it lands in form_invalid() and the form.errors say 'this field is required' for the length and name field.

```
class Service(models.Model):
    TIME_CHOICES = (
        (15, '15 minutes'),
        (30, '30 minutes'),
        )
    length = models.FloatField(choices=TIME_CHOICES,max_length=6)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class ServiceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Service

ServiceFormSet = modelformset_factory(Service,form=ServiceForm)

class ServiceEditView(CreateView):
    template_name = "service_formset.html"
    model = Service
    form_class = ServiceForm
    success_url = 'works/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context['formset']
        if formset.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('works/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('doesnt-work/')

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print form.errors
        return HttpResponseRedirect('doesnt-work/')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ServiceEditView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if self.request.POST:
            context['formset'] = ServiceFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['formset'] = ServiceFormSet(queryset=Service.objects.filter(user__exact=self.request.user.id))
        return context
```

## My question is

How can I use a createview to handle a formset? 
What am I missing to get it do validate correctly?

The tutorial I've taken most of the bits from so far http://haineault.com/blog/155/

### In short, what I've done so far

Since the form.errors variable say each field is required, I think it expects a regular form not a formset -> I'm missing some option that tell the CreateView it's a formset.

I've also tried the solution suggested here: http://www.kevinbrolly.com/.

```
class BaseServiceFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseServiceFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.empty_permitted = False
```

But it didnt make any difference.

Comment: "What am I missing to get it do validate correctly, or how can I use a createview to handle a formset?" can you refine this question please ? What are your expectations ? Also, can you post your template ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Solution

pip install django-extra-views

And in *view.py*:

```
from extra_views import FormSetView
class ItemFormSetView(ModelFormSetView):
    model = Service
    template_name = 'service_formset.html'
```

There's a discussion about getting this into Django core, but the discussions seems to have stagnated.
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16256

### Where I found the solution

At this repository https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views
there's a view called ModelFormSetView, which does exactly what I needed.
It's a class-based view, that does the same as CreateView, but for formsets.

Answer (score 0):

> Django go into form_invalid() and the form.errors say 'this field is required' for the length and name field.

This is normal and due to the [required field paramatere](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#required):

> By default, each Field class assumes the value is required, so if you
>   pass an empty value -- either None or the empty string ("") -- then
>   clean() will raise a ValidationError exception:

If you want to inverse that, you can set **required=False**:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    TIME_CHOICES = (
        (15, '15 minutes'),
        (30, '30 minutes'),
        )
    length = models.FloatField(choices=TIME_CHOICES,max_length=6, required=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, required=False)
```

> What am I missing to get it do validate correctly

Did you try to post a form with name **and** length values ?

Comment: I found a solution here: https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views The view "ModelFormSetView" is exactly what I needed. Apparently there's a discussion about getting that view into the Django core, but it seems to have stagnated. Will post the solution in 7 hours (dont have enough reputation to post the solution now)